# Is it safe that everybody can see my JavaScript validation functions?

Tags: javascript, php, validation, security

In my signup page, I do validation using both JavaScript and PHP.

However, people can see my JavaScript validation functions by viewing the source of the web page. It contains input fields names, ids etc.

[image]

So, is it safe that anybody can see them ?

Comment: Not being a security expert here, but I don't think there's a lot you can actually do about it, while this might validate them client side, I would recommend that you also do validating server side.

Comment: As long as you don't provide any "confidential" information, like passwords and so on to the client, that's good enough. If the validation part related to the pure sign in (username, password, email and so on) is done on the SERVER SIDE and is properly escaped and stored, then it's totally ok.

Comment: You can never trust client side validation, it's really only there to provide a better user experience. It's not "dangerous" that people can see the validation logic unless you're not also validating server-side, which it sounds like you are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The validation functions you've quoted don't reveal any information that it seems like you need to keep secret (quite the opposite, actually, telling people what is and isn't required is useful and could make its way to the UI). So they're "safe" in that they don't reveal anything confidential.

If you have validation functions that use information or techniques that you want to keep secret, you'll need to move them to the server, as they wouldn't be "safe" as they'd be revealing confidential information.

You can make it *harder* for people to understand your client-side validation functions by using an aggressive minifier/obfuscator, such as Google Closure Compiler in advanced mode. But you can't make it impossible: If the browser can read the code, people using the browser can read the code.

---

And just because we're talking about client-side validation, the usual warning: Even though you're validating client-side, you still have to validate server-side. Users can bypass your client-side code and send in invalid information.

Comment: What about using objects calling from some external file so people don't get an idea from which file the code is written and what actually is the code for that portion of js function?

Comment: @KeepCoding: Well, I'd probably do that anyway, just because I prefer the JavaScript off in its own file. But again, if it's client-side, it's visible. Casual observers probably aren't the issue anyway; people who will step through your code in a debugger, which will find it no matter where it is, would be the bigger issue I'd think.

Comment: Yes I'm doing a complete validation with these functions in the serverside section.    mysql_real_escape_string, str_replace , preg_replace  So...., thanks for the detailed explanation...

Answer (score 2):

It is safe since your code is reflecting the actions on your page. When you define a max length on your code, you show that to your users by providing some UI and messages. Nothing secretive here, so that's ok.

Also, when you move to production from development, you should consider [minifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) and [obfuscating](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) your javascript code to hide your sensitive code from praying eyes. That way you save on bandwith, and add an extra layer of security for your application.

Comment: Thanks... will see about those minifying and obfuscating methods... Had never heard of them before. Thanks for letting me know...

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that you know of them now. These two, are going to be your good friends while publishing your client side apps ;)

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript validation part is not really that much of a security concern because users cant modify or misuse anything if they get pass it but it's the PHP validation that you should be careful with as if compromised, can allow a user to access your database (if your form is linked with your db of course).

Comment: OK, I do a complete validation with escaping in the PHP code...  Thanks... :)

Comment: No prob :) @TharinduLucky

Answer (score 1):

Javascript validation works on client side .if some one has disabled his browsers Javascript .it wont works . and moreover there are no much security concerns in showing javascript validation.Always do Server side validation to avoid any type of misconsequences or security measures. in simple

> Java script << Client Side Validation
>    PHP << Server Side Validation.